# Problems downloading something-something datasets

Tags: python-3.x, computer-vision, dataset

I am now learning video recognition and want to use the dataset something-something published by twentybn(https://www.twentybn.com/datasets/something-something).

I followed the downloading and installing tips in https://github.com/TwentyBN/twentybn-dl, which told me to download the dataset in the virtual environment.

When process reached 'extract-chunks' step, something wrong occurred like

```
Using: '/home/hanzp/sth_sth' as storage.
Will now extract chunks for: 'something-something'
100%|████████████████████████████████▉| 5.33M/5.33M [19:19<00:00, 19.4Kimages/s]Exception in thread background thread for pid 30664:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/hanzp/twentybn-dl/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sh.py", line 1540, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hanzp/twentybn-dl/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sh.py", line 2459, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/hanzp/twentybn-dl/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sh.py", line 2157, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/hanzp/twentybn-dl/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2: 

  RAN: /bin/tar xvz

  STDOUT:
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00045.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00019.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00003.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00062.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00057.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00014.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00040.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00011.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00021.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00008.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00027.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00028.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00050.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00034.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00063.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00007.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00009.jpg
20... (137762091 more, please see e.stdout)

  STDERR:
/bin/tar: 20bn-something-something-v1/27730：无法 mkdir: 过多的连接
/bin/tar: 20bn-something-something-v1/27730/00043.jpg：无法 open: 没有那个文件或目录
/bin/tar: 20bn-something-something-v1/27730：无法 mkdir: 过多的连接
/bin/tar: 20bn-something-something-v1/27730/00066.jpg：无法 open: 没有那个文件或目录
/bin/tar: 20bn-something-something-v1/27730：无法 mkdir: 过多的连接
/bin/tar: 20bn-something-something-v1/27730/00049.jpg：无法 open: 没有那个文件或目录
/bin/tar: 20bn-something-something-v1/27730：无法 mkdir: 过多的连接
/bin/tar: 20bn-something-something-v1/27730/00001.jpg：无法 open: 没有那个文件或目录
/bin/tar: 20bn-something-something-v1/27730：无法 mkdir... (271684964 more, please see e.stderr)

100%|█████████████████████████████████| 5.33M/5.33M [19:26<00:00, 4.57Kimages/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hanzp/twentybn-dl/bin/twentybn-dl", line 6, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/hanzp/twentybn-dl/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twentybn_dl/cli.py", line 108, in main
    extract_chunks(d)
  File "/home/hanzp/twentybn-dl/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twentybn_dl/cli.py", line 49, in extract_chunks
    d.extract_chunks()
  File "/home/hanzp/twentybn-dl/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twentybn_dl/schema.py", line 100, in extract_chunks
    extract_chunks(self.chunk_paths, self.jpegs, self.storage)
  File "/home/hanzp/twentybn-dl/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twentybn_dl/extract.py", line 31, in extract_chunks
    for line in process:
  File "/home/hanzp/twentybn-dl/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sh.py", line 863, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/hanzp/twentybn-dl/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sh.py", line 792, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/hanzp/twentybn-dl/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2: 

  RAN: /bin/tar xvz

  STDOUT:
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00045.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00019.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00003.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00062.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00057.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00014.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00040.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00011.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00021.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00008.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00027.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00028.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00050.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00034.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00063.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00007.jpg
20bn-something-something-v1/16296/00009.jpg
20... (137762091 more, please see e.stdout)

  STDERR:
/bin/tar: 20bn-something-something-v1/27730：无法 mkdir: 过多的连接
/bin/tar: 20bn-something-something-v1/27730/00043.jpg：无法 open: 没有那个文件或目录
/bin/tar: 20bn-something-something-v1/27730：无法 mkdir: 过多的连接
/bin/tar: 20bn-something-something-v1/27730/00066.jpg：无法 open: 没有那个文件或目录
/bin/tar: 20bn-something-something-v1/27730：无法 mkdir: 过多的连接
/bin/tar: 20bn-something-something-v1/27730/00049.jpg：无法 open: 没有那个文件或目录
/bin/tar: 20bn-something-something-v1/27730：无法 mkdir: 过多的连接
/bin/tar: 20bn-something-something-v1/27730/00001.jpg：无法 open: 没有那个文件或目录
/bin/tar: 20bn-something-something-v1/27730：无法 mkdir... (271684964 more, please see e.stderr)
```

Maybe i use chinese environment in my ubuntu. The chinese part is

can't mkdir: too much connection

can't open: no such file or directory

Actually i have successfully installed 60k videos but the number of total videos is 100k.

Anyone knew this dataset have met the same problem? Or anyone knew how to do with this error?

Really thanks

Comment: Please paste the traceback log here, not a picture.

Comment: Perhaps, the error was emitted from l.23 in [this module](https://github.com/TwentyBN/twentybn-dl/blob/master/src/main/python/twentybn_dl/extract.py), but I'm not sure what is the problem nor how to solve...

Comment: @dkato thank you for giving me advice. I got the same feeling as you. Error was there but don't know how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I myself have solved this problem. My translation may be wrong that the actual chinese part is 'can't mkdir: too many links'. That is the key that in my ubuntu system only 60k subfolder is permitted in each folder, so this error occurred. I used another computer and downloaded and extracted the dataset successfully.

Comment: hello @Hanzp, I cannot access the website (https://www.twentybn.com/datasets/something-something), could you mirror your something-something-v1 dataset? Thx